# When Should I use 'the' with months, seasons?

Tags: articles

Should I say:

> There are four seasons of (the) year?
>
> Today we will talk about  names of (the) months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two sentences would be more likely to occur as

> There are four seasons in the year.

and

> Today we're going to talk about the names of the months.

*Year* and *month* are preceded by *the* because both are definite. In other contexts they might not be.

Comment: Maybe AmE v BrE but I would say "There are four seasons in *a* year" -- but better still would be "There are four seasons *per* year".

Comment: Or just: *Today we’re going to talk about month names.* Non-native speakers often put a lot more ‘of the’ constructs in than they really need to (obviously not you, of course), and don’t think to make noun–noun constructs, using the noun attributively as though it were an adjective.

Comment: I prefer *...about names of months* to *...about the names of the months* but [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=names+of+months%2Cnames+of+the+months&year_start=1785&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) supports the assertion that *...names of the months* is more likely to occur than is *...names of months*.